# Display user 'My Documents' in a Page Viewer Web Part

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I'm currently using a Page Viewer Web Part in SharePoint 2013 to display our network drive on the home page. Is there a way to do this for user profile documents on the same network?

For example, I currently use the path `file://\\data\company\` to display these files, but user files are located in the path `file://\\data\username$\` (suffixed with dollar sign for hidden folder)

[image]

Is there a way I can insert the current users username into the page viewer web part to display their documents?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried either esacping or url encoding the $ within your file path?

Comment: That isn't the problem. I'm looking to insert the current users username into the file path inside the page viewer web part so I can retrieve their documents on a network drive.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a SharePoint environment now, but you can use the CURRENT USER FILTER WEB PART in the same page, after you insert the filter mentioned, you should create a connection with the Page Viewer web Part and try to change the "Path Property" with a composite text. 

Comment your result please!!


Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply! I'm trying this now, I'll let you know how it goes :)